# GoogleMap onComplete callback

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I am using Google Maps API v2 and for any reason I need to know, when the map is completely shown. Ho can I do that? Is there any callback listener?

Comment: Not available see here and click on the star so it does get worked on.  http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=5712

Answer (score 1):

Can you share why are you looking for this? Maybe there are another solution.

Anyway, I'm just wondering that maybe you can use the [GoogleMap.OnCameraChangeListener](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.OnCameraChangeListener). It's a kind of ugly hack because the method onCameraChange was not design for this proposal, but maybe it works.

> public abstract void onCameraChange (CameraPosition position)
>
> Called after the camera position has changed. During an animation,
>   this listener may not be notified of intermediate camera positions. It
>   is always called for the final position in the animation.
>
> This is called on the main thread.

Comment: +1 It is possible to use. but have to check it wasn't just map loading which is a camera change event with latitude 0.0 and longitude 0.0.